# How to log full POST request in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

This is trivia, but can not find good example.
I have following function for sending POST requests:

```
static func sendArrival(scan: ArrivalScan){
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "api.my.url.com"
        urlComponents.path = "/Delivery/Arrival/?id="
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else { fatalError("Could not create URL from components") }

        // Specify this request as being a POST method
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        // Make sure that we include headers specifying that our request's HTTP body
        // will be JSON encoded
        var headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields ?? [:]
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        headers["ZM_APIKey"] = "mySecretKey"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        // Now let's encode out Post struct into JSON data...
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let jsonData = try encoder.encode(scan)
            // ... and set our request's HTTP body
            request.httpBody = jsonData
            print("jsonData: ", String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "no body data")
        } catch {
            //TODO: error handling
        }

        // Create and run a URLSession data task with our JSON encoded POST request
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
            guard responseError == nil else {
                //TODO: error handling
                return
            }

            // APIs usually respond with the data you just sent in your POST request
            if let data = responseData, let utf8Representation = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("response: ", utf8Representation)
            } else {
                print("no readable data received in response")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

But something is not working. To decode I need to see full request (in format it will hit server). How to print this?

Comment: I think the best way is to use a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org). It eliminates all ambiguity.

Comment: By the way, if it's not working, I'd suggest you look at `responseError`, rather than just returning. Likewise, if `responseData` is not `nil`, you should examine that, because for certain web service errors, it can contain useful information (if not `nil`).

Comment: FWIW, that `allHTTPHeaderFields` pattern is a little unusual. Usually you'd just call `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` and `request.setValue("mySecretKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "ZM_APIKey")` and be done with it.

Comment: @Rob, You are correct if you just need to add a single few fields to a particular request. But if you have multiple requests that will all have the same header values I like to store a dictionary in class and then just set `allHTTPHeaderFields = commonHeaders` and then add any that are specific to that request.

Comment: Agreed, but that's not what he's doing here. It just feels like convoluted way of doing it in his `sendArrival` method.

Answer (score 9):

To see much of the information in the request printed to the console, you can use:

```
dump(request)
```

A better option in my opinion is to use a tool like Charles or Wireshark, as Rob mentions above in the comments.

Comment: I've never needed more than `request.debugDescription`. But I agree, and in all honesty OP probably needs to check his responses before he immediately assumes there is an issue with how he built his request.